# Why some actions appear bold in Construct 2?

Tags: html, user-interface, action, bold, construct-2

I am trying to get started with Construct 2 and notice that some actions appear in bold (Visible and Invisible in the screenshot below). What does it mean? Also, it seems like the last one only does so.

[image]

PS - It seems that it only happens for events related to buttons (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure about that, but it seems that buttons manipulate the visible/invisible property different, like it's not a native feature.

So I would check the possibility of visible and invisible acting like instance variables for buttons. I will investigate further when I am on my Windows PC and get back to you.